# Storage Access in Doze Mode

Tags: java, android

Is this true that doze mode might block access to storage?

For some time I'm struggling that my application's alarms are blocked in doze mode even tho I set them with "setExactAndAllowWhileIdle" method, but my alarms have notifications that get title, icon and description from database.

Could it be problem with accessing storage(in my case databases) in doze mode?

If so, any ideas to prevent this problem?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this true that doze mode might block access to storage?

That is not documented behavior, if that is what you mean. And I have not seen it in practice.